# Table of frequency of specific scores in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a table of frequency and percent by container, class, and score.

```
 df = pd.read_csv('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pL8fHCc25-XRBYgj9n6NdRt5VHrIr-p1/view?usp=sharing', sep=',')                                                                 
  df.groupby([ 'Containe', 'Class']).count()
```

The output should be:

[image]

But that script does not work!

Comment: Which problem do you encounter and what is your question?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: The data sample can be download in the link 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pL8fHCc25-XRBYgj9n6NdRt5VHrIr-p1/view?usp=sharing.  That script does not work!

Answer (score 0):

First, we `stack` the values in order to have one by rows :

```py
>>> df1 = (df.set_index(["Containe", "Class"])
...          .stack()
...          .reset_index(name='Score')
...          .rename(columns={'level_2':'letters'}))
```

Then, we use a `groupby` to get the `size` of each combinaison of values like so :

```py
>>> df_grouped = df1.groupby(['Containe', 'Class', 'letters', 'Score'], as_index=False).size()
```

To finish, we use the `pivot_table` method to get the expected result :

```py
>>> pd.pivot_table(df_grouped, values='size', index=['letters', 'Class', 'Containe'], columns=['Score']).fillna(0)
                   Score    0     1     2
letters Class   Containe            
AB      A              1    2.0   1.0   1.0
                       2    1.0   2.0   1.0
        B              3    2.0   1.0   1.0
                       4    1.0   2.0   1.0
AC      A              1    0.0   2.0   2.0
                       2    1.0   2.0   1.0
        B              3    1.0   2.0   1.0
                       4    2.0   2.0   0.0
AD      A              1    2.0   0.0   2.0
                       2    1.0   3.0   0.0
        B              3    2.0   1.0   1.0
                       4    1.0   1.0   2.0
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot!